# How to accumulate the total execution of a while loop which is within a for loop?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to accumulate the total attempts of a conditional while loop of actions which is within a for loop for repeat testing the stability of the while-looping action. (using Selenium framework)

Tried to change the loop method or setting variables, using all the ways I could think of and looked through the community, seem no people encountered similar situation.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  for (int loop = 1; loop <= 10; loop++) {
    System.out.println("Loop count: " + loop);
    boolean retry = true;
    int i = 1;
    while (retry == true) {
      int t = i++;
      //...
      System.out.println("Test case 1 - Start Run " + t);
      try {
         // my testing script of actions
        System.out.println("Test case 1 - Run Success, finished by " 
            + t + " execution(s)");
        retry = false;
        break;
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Test case 1 - Run " 
            + t + " Failed, retry...");
      } 
      driver.quit();
    }
  }
}
```

The code is to test the stability of the action script (in Selenium webdriver framework) with auto retry without human interruption when there is exception errors (normally it would stops the script entirely) by looping the whole thing and see how many attempts it actually needs to complete 10 successful runs (print out and accumulate the total t at the end of each for-loop count).
Put it in another way, I would like to count the total attempts it took (within the retry loop) to reach 10 successful runs (for loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not keep the total count outside both loops?

```
int totalCount = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {

  while (retry) {
    totalCount ++;
    // do your thing
  }
}

System.out.println("Took " + totalCount + " attempts to get 10 successfully");
```